# How to write unittest to test Add-on

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

How to write unit tests in blender and how to compile them to see there are running perfectly.
note: unit tests to test add-on. Thank you.

Comment: Here's one example of a Blender addon's unit tests : https://github.com/IfcOpenShell/IfcOpenShell/tree/v0.7.0/src/blenderbim/test

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to test is independent of bpy in any way, then you extract what you test into its own method and use @pytest as normal.
If you want to test it *with* bpy (calling operators, setting properties), then you'll need to install pytest into Blender's library (need pip too), run Blender headless, and run the unit tests through Blender. I used [blender-addon-tester on github](https://github.com/nangtani/blender-addon-tester) to handle most of this, however it's not the smoothest experience and there's lots of setup that still has to be done manually.